# PHP array from MySQL result has duplicate values due to subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I've used a MySQL query to get an array of results into PHP. However, the query uses a subquery and can result in the subquery value being shown twice in the array which is incorrect. I spent ages looking at the SQL to see if I could stop this but wasn't successful at all. I now wonder if it is easier to just modify the array to rectify this error.

**The array:**

```
    array(436) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "75"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(8) "168.0000"
    ["invoice_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["adjustment"]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
    ["totalcost"]=>
    string(8) "168.0000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "82"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(7) "84.0000"
    ["invoice_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["adjustment"]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
    ["totalcost"]=>
    string(7) "84.0000"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "86"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(8) "224.0000"
    ["invoice_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["adjustment"]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
    ["totalcost"]=>
    string(8) "224.0000"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "95"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(7) "70.0000"
    ["invoice_type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["adjustment"]=>
    string(4) "9.00"
    ["totalcost"]=>
    string(7) "70.0000"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "95"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(7) "84.0000"
    ["invoice_type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["adjustment"]=>
    string(4) "9.00"
    ["totalcost"]=>
    string(7) "84.0000"
  }
```

**The problem:**

In the SQL, the result is grouped by the "invoice_type" then "id". The SQL uses a subquery to get the value for "adjustment". If the result has "invoice_type = 1" AND "invoice_type = 2", both items are added to the array but the adjustment value is also added to both which I don't want as it gets doubled.

Is there a simple way to see if "id" is duplicated and if it is, set one of the "adjustment" values to 0.00?

If you think I should really cover this in the SQL, I'd be happy to add more information regarding that part too.

I've been staring at this for too long now and can't see any other options ;-)

**EDIT - The SQL:**

```
SELECT tbl_client.id, tbl_client.first_name, tbl_client.surname, tbl_schedule.invoice_type, sum( duration ) AS totalhours, sum( duration * rate ) AS subtotal, ifnull( adjustment.totaladjustment, 0 ) AS adjustment, (
sum( duration * rate ) + ifnull( adjustment.totaladjustment, 0 )
) AS totalcost
FROM `tbl_schedule`
INNER JOIN tbl_client ON tbl_client.id = tbl_schedule.client
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT client, sum( amount ) AS totaladjustment
    FROM tbl_invoice_adjustment
    WHERE ( tbl_invoice_adjustment.`date` BETWEEN 1357002061 AND 1359676740 )
    GROUP BY client
    ) adjustment ON adjustment.client = tbl_schedule.client
WHERE tbl_schedule.franchise =1
AND ( STATUS =1 OR `status` =2 OR `status` =4 )
AND `date` BETWEEN 1357002061 AND 1359676740
GROUP BY tbl_schedule.invoice_type, tbl_schedule.client
ORDER BY tbl_client.surname ASC
```

**EDIT - Table structure**

### tbl_client

id
franchise
title
surname
first_name

### tbl_schedule

id
franchise
date
client
invoice_type
duration
rate
status

### tbl_invoice_adjustment

id
franchise
client
date
description
amount

The idea is that the query should pull in adjustments for a given time period and combine them with the schedule values. It was all good till I started implementing this adjustment thing. It is 99.7% OK except for the rare case where there are multiple "invoice_type" entries for a given client in a single period.

**EDIT: - SQL Fiddle**

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f9bc00/1/0) of the problem.

If you run the statement, you will see that client ID 5 is given the adjustment twice though there is only one adjustment for the client in the database. The main query shows two rows because the grouping is by the invoice_type. Each result row runs the subquery and gets the adjustment.

The fiddle shows the required output but the statement is not fixed in any way.

Comment: what does your query look like ?

Comment: Hi @Maximus2012 , the SQL has been added.

Comment: can you also post the structure of your tables that you are using in the query ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 - No problem. Struggled a bit with Markdown there but hopefully you will see. I've removed a lot of fields for clarity.

Comment: Just clarify, though I have made changes above and sdded the SQL as per @Maximus2012 's request, I'd still be happy with an array hack solution to the problem. I'm considering a complete rewrite which will be aright pain.

Comment: can you try using distinct clause in your select statement to see if that makes any difference ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Tried that and no difference. I think that's because the subquery is correct against the main query still.

Comment: what should your ideal output from this query look like ?

Comment: Can you also create an sqlfiddle if possible with these 3 tables and some sample data : http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 The fiddle is linked above and the output shown is the desired result but without the duplicate adjustment as described above.

Comment: see if this helps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f9bc00/6 I replaced GROUP BY tbl_schedule.invoice_type, tbl_schedule.client with 
    GROUP BY tbl_schedule.client but not sure if this will give you the correct result for all the cases.

Comment: Thanks @Maximus2012 but that won't work. It needs to show if there are multiple invoice_type entries. This is how I've ended up going in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using the PHP method and running over the array making the change where necessary. Works perfectly for my needs.

```
 $showerror = false;
    $lineid = array();
    foreach ($empresults as $invoiceline => $line) {
        if (isset($lineid[$line['id']])) {
            $empresults[$invoiceline]['duplicate'] = true;
            $empresults[$lineid[$line['id']]]['duplicate'] = true;
            if ($empresults[$lineid[$line['id']]]['adjustment'] != 0) {
                $empresults[$lineid[$line['id']]]['totalcost'] = $empresults[$lineid[$line['id']]]['totalcost'] - $empresults[$lineid[$line['id']]]['adjustment'];
                $empresults[$lineid[$line['id']]]['adjustment'] = 0;
            }
            $showerror = true;
        } else {
            $empresults[$invoiceline]['duplicate'] = false;
        }
        $lineid[$line['id']] = $invoiceline;
    }
```